# Can I streamline pattern matching files and copying them to folders to sort them?

Tags: python, sorting, copy

So I am very much a newbie at coding in general, not just Python.

I wrote some code to sort out files and copy them into separate folders so it's easier for me to then send the right files to the right recipients.

These files get dumped into one folder and using search functions was getting tedious.

So after some false starts this code works and does its job, but I'll have to copy and paste these code blocks for each recipient and change the parameters.

I'm just wondering if there is a more streamlined approach to this, as it seems quite clunky to do it this way.

```
    import os, shutil

dir = ('{the directory the files get dumped into}')

pattern = 'Karl H. Preusse'
matching_files_Karl = [f for f in os.listdir(dir) if pattern in f]
dest_dir = '{the directory the files get dumped into}\\Karl'

for file_name in matching_files_Karl:
    full_Karl_File_Name = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_Karl_File_Name):
        shutil.copy(full_Karl_File_Name, dest_dir)


pattern = 'Rom'
matching_files_Rom = [f for f in os.listdir(dir) if pattern in f]
dest_dir = '{the directory the files get dumped into}\\ROM'

for file_name in matching_files_Rom:
    full_Rom_File_Name = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_Rom_File_Name):
        shutil.copy(full_Rom_File_Name, dest_dir)


pattern = 'Hochschule'
matching_files_Hochschule = [f for f in os.listdir(dir) if pattern in f]
dest_dir = '{the directory the files get dumped into}\\Heldele\\Hochschule'

for file_name in matching_files_Hochschule:
    full_Hochschule_File_Name = os.path.join(dir, file_name)
    if os.path.isfile(full_Hochschule_File_Name):
        shutil.copy(full_Hochschule_File_Name, dest_dir)
```

Comment: *"I wrote some code to sort out files and copy them into separate folders "* - show it!

Comment: Seems you're telling a story. Would like to see the code though

Comment: So sorry, I was putting in the tags and hit enter and it just posted the post before I got the code in! :(

Comment: Are you seeing a pattern?

Comment: I do, and it seems like some form of if structure might do the trick to go through all the possible recipents, but I think that might just complicate the thing more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

dir = ('{the directory the files get dumped into}')

files = os.listdir(dir)

user_data = [
    ('Karl H. Preusse', 'dest dir for Karl'),
    ('Rom', 'dest dir for Rom'),
]

for pattern, dest_dir in user_data:
    matching_files = [f for f in files if pattern in f]
    for filename in matching_files:
        full_filename = os.path.join(dir, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(full_filename):
            shutil.copy(full_filename, dest_dir)
```

Comment: This works wonderfully and is also faster! I don't quite understand how user_data defines both pattern and dest_dir, though? As far as I can tell it just makes a list with tuples?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of tuple of pattern and user's destination directory.